# Trying to launch PowerShell from the file explorer location bar open the PowerShell directory in my documents instead of launching the console

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-explorer

I use very frequently the trick of putting `cmd` or `powershell` in the file explorer location to start a new console at the same path as the file explorer.

However, I cannot start PowerShell with that trick anymore. When I try to input `powershell`, it open the following directory instead of opening a console : `C:\Users\{username}\Documents\PowerShell`.

Deleting the `PowerShell` folder "fixes" the issue. My guess is that, by default, if a folder in `Documents` has the same name as what you type in the location bar, it will open that folder.

So my question is : how can I disable this behavior ? So that I can have a `PowerShell` folder in `Documents` and still launch PowerShell from the location bar.

Comment: it works on my end. Which OS version are you on?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Enterprise (OS build 19042.1415) right now.

Comment: Works for me also. Try it when booting in Safe Mode. If this still happens, and as you're using Windows 10 version 20H2, you should upgrade to 21H2 (which you should do anyway). (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but it isn't too hard to create a shortcut that will open powershell pointed at the "current directory".  Just create a regular shortcut, edit it, and blank out the target directory,  Then just put this short cut in the target directory, navigate to that folder with explorer, and use the shortcut.

Comment: @harrymc It's not linked to safe mode or the windows version. Actually, deleting the `C:\Users\{username}\Documents\PowerShell` folder actually "solve" the issue. However it is bothering to no be able to have user specific PowerShell module at this location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the folder
`C:\Users\{username}\Documents\PowerShell`
is in your PATH.

This explains why typing `powershell` opens the folder rather than the
program.

If you want to keep on using `powershell` this way, you may either:

- Type instead : `powershell.exe`
- Remove `C:\Users\{username}\Documents` from your PATH.

Comment: Indeed `powershell.exe` works well. Removing `Documents` from the PATH too. Nice answer !

Answer (score 0):

You can get a context menu (right click menu) entry that will open a powershell console at the location that was right clicked.

1. Open regedit
2. Navigate to: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell
3. Right-click the `shell` key and choose New > Key. Name the new key    `openpowershellhere`. You can call it what you want, but not `Powershell` because that key name already exists.
4. With the `openpowershellhere` key selected, double-click the    (Default) value to open its properties window.
5. Set the value in the “Value data” box to `Open PowerShell Here`
6. OPTIONAL step to make it so that to option only appears if you hold    Shift down while right-clicking (*the same way that the “Open Command    Prompt” command is hidden unless you Shift+right-click a folder*):

   - Right-click the `openpowershellhere` key and choose New > String    Value.
   - Name the new value `Extended`. You don’t need to make any    changes to it. Just having that string there will cause the command    to be hidden behind Shift key access.
7. Next we need to create a new key inside your `openpowershellhere`    key. Right-click the `openpowershellhere` key and choose New > Key.    Name the new key `command`.
8. With the `command` key selected, double-click the (Default) value to    open its properties window.
9. Type the following text into the “Value data” box and then click OK:    `C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe    -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%L'`

The changes should take place immediately, so you can exit out of    Registry Editor. To test it out, just right-click (or    Shift+right-click if you set up that option) any folder and make    choose the ”Open with PowerShell” command.

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer. I can already have this context menu using `shift + right click`. This is indeed quite practical. However this is not what I'm looking for. I would like to understand why the explorer location bar method is no longer working for me.

Comment: ok, so the real issue was that your PATH variable had the powershell folder in it which screwed up how the location bar in explorer decided what to do when powershell was typed in... makes sense... glad you sorted it out

Answer (score 0):

## Quick and simple way to start PowerShell via Windows terminal

Type `wt` into address bar of file explorer to open Windows terminal.

**Windows terminal** can be set to start as PowerShell 1.0 (basic version that comes with Windows) but also newest PowerShell 7++, git bash, cmd, etc.

For me It's faster to write `wt` instead of `powershell.exe` and it doesn't matter if there's PS folder in my documents.

To start Windows terminal at current directory use `wt -d .`